# Javascript - read Java's ObjectOutputStream

Tags: javascript, java

So, I came to the conclusion that writing multiple (2D) arrays in binary format `(ByteArrayOutputStream)` using `ObjectOutputStream` is way faster than writing it by my self (i.e looping through all the 2d arrays and write the values) or by `JSON`.

Now, I'm transporting the output of the `ObjectOutputStream` in bytes from the server to the client, and I want to read these bytes on the client side.

How can I read the output of `ObjectOutputStream` in `javascript`?

Comment: You need to de-serialize your instance ... it might not be possible based on what your are sending. It would have been simpler to use an API to build your JSON array.

Comment: The reason I don't use JSON is because it takes me 7224ms (7s) to build the packet I want to send to the client, and the packet length will be 14mb. If I use ObjectOutputStream, the packet will be built in 116ms with a length of 6,2mb. This is a huge significant difference for me.

Comment: The time you gain on that generation will be a time lost in dev and on th client side ... (if this is even possble to decode an instance without a valid `serialVersionUID`). Give an example of what you serialize put in that stream please (an [mcve])

Comment: Don't use `ObjectStreams` when working with non-Java parties. It uses a Java serialization mechanism, so only use it if you're working with a Java only environment (and even then, I wouldn't recommend it). If you don't want to use JSON, then create your own protocol and adhere to that. It should be just as fast, but less dependent on Java serialization.

Comment: @AxelH While creating my example class, I found out why JSON was slow for me. I converted the data to a JSON string, then to a JSON object, and then I called the toString method. It takes 3 seconds now, which is way better. I might as well delete this question.

Comment: @Kayaman Thanks for the information. Really helped me understanding how Java made the file that small.